# Couldn't send and store String data to database through WCF

Tags: sql-server, wcf, windows-store-apps

I have created a Windows 8 app, I have a table in SQL server database to store people's name, " [Name] VARCHAR (50)"

I have manage to send and save integer values to database, but when i modified my coding to store the string, it does not work, table data is empty. Please help!

itemDetail.html

```
<div>
<input id="join1" type="text" />
<button id="joinbtn">insert</button>
</div>
```

itemDetail.js

```
var joinButton = document.getElementById('joinbtn');
        // Register Click event
        joinButton.addEventListener("click", joinButtonClick, false);

        function joinButtonClick() {
            // Retrieve element
            var baseURI2 = "http://localhost:45573/AddService.svc/Join";
            var jointext = document.getElementById('join1').value;

            WinJS.xhr({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseURI2,
                headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                data: '{"namet":' + jointext + '}'
            }).then(function complete(request) {
                var resdata = request.responseText;
            }, function error(er) {
                var err = er.statusText;
            })
        }
```

AddService.svc.cs

```
public void Join(string namet)
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Table2(Name) VALUES (@Name)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", namet);
        try
               {
            con.Open();
            int numAff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
            con.Close();
    }
```

IAddService.cs

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    void Join(string namet);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, but there isn't much info in your question to go on. If I was debugging this, I'd a) make sure Join() is called by hard coding some bogus data in the function and then checking the database to see if it arrived. If the function's being reached, I'd b) make sure nameT has some data by writing the value to a log or something. Put in a catch block, too, and output your error somewhere. Just a suggestion.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I was confused, the code above works fine if i want to store integer value entered by user. I just made minor changes like "int" change to "string", also create new table with 1 column, Name VARCHAR[50]. The app runs fine, but after i enter a word and click button, the database table data is empty?

Comment: Since you have access to the code, I assume you can start the program in debug mode. I'd put a breakpoint where the sql call is made. Then, using a client app or test harness, step through the code to see what's going on. Put in a catch statement, too, and output any errors to the event log.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in this line

```
data: '{"namet":' + jointext + '}'
```

Try changing it to

```
data: '{"namet":\'' + jointext + '\'}'
```